# ATM's to buy Monero

Tags: mymonero, exchange

Is it possible buy Monero with cash at an ATM? If so, how do I find one in the Virginia Beach area?  Which ATM's sell Monero? I have a wallet already.

Comment: coinatmradar.com  But they are very few out there that do XMR.  Can buy LTC and exchange on tradeogre.

Answer (score 1):

Check out ATM data aggregator websites. An example can be found at https://coinatmradar.com/

There are some ATMs that sell Monero, even though they are rare.